# How can we store object of derived type into pointers of base type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, object-slicing

I am having difficulty in understanding how we can store objects of derived type into pointer of base type.

```
class Base
{
    int a;    // An object of A would be of 4 bytes
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    int b;    //This makes Derived of 8 bytes
};

int main()
{
    Base* obj = new Derived();    // Is this consistent? I am trying to store objects of Derived type into memory meant for Base type
 
    delete obj;

    return 0;
}
```

I see this format being used extensively for achieving run-time polymorphism. I am just wondering if there is a way to access non-inherited data members (`b` in this case) of `Derived` object using `obj`.

Does doing `Base* obj = new Derived();` result in object slicing? If so, why is this model prevalent for achieving polymorphism?

Comment: If you're talking about polymorphism, you should be dealing with code example that uses polymorphism.

Comment: For `Base* obj = new Derived();`, the static type of `obj` is `Base*`, and the dynamic type of `obj` is `Derived*`.

Comment: Yes, use a virtual function defined in Base and overridden in Derived.

Comment: Be careful with terminology. The code is **not** storing **objects** of Derived type. It is storing a **pointer** to an object. There are no `Base` objects in this code. There is one `Derived` object, created by `new Derived()`; its **address** is stored in the pointer named `obj`. The `Derived` object has a `Base` sub-object; the `new` handled all of the memory requirements for that.

Comment: Thanks @Pete Becker for clarifying this. I chose my words wrongly. I was just wondering whether b would be accessible using obj as it is.

Answer (score 0):

> I am just wondering if there is a way to access non-inherited data members (`b` in this case) of `Derived` object using `obj`.

Not when using `obj` as-is by itself, because `b` is not a member of `Base`.

But, *IF AND ONLY IF*  `obj` is pointing at a `Derived` (or descendant) object, you can **type cast** `obj` to a `Derived*` pointer in order to directly access members of `Derived`.

Otherwise, another option is to define a `virtual` method in `Base` that `Derived` can override to access its own members as needed. You can then call that method via `obj` as-is.

> Does doing `Base* obj = new Derived();` result in object slicing?

No. A `Derived` object is also a valid `Base` object, so `obj` is simply pointing at the `Base` portion of the `Derived` object. Object slicing occurs when you assign an *instance* of a derived class to an *instance* of a base class, in which case only the base portion can be assigned. But assigning a *pointer* to another *pointer* does not assign the objects that they are pointing at.

Comment: Thanks @Remy for your answer. It clarified a lot of things for me. Also I performed a static_cast on obj to convert it to Derived* type and indeed I was able to access member b via it.

Comment: @Kshitij_9192 use `static_cast` only when you KNOW FOR SURE that `obj` points at a specific type. If you DON'T KNOW FOR SURE, use `dynamic_cast` instead, and test the result for failure before using it.

Comment: Thanks Remy for the note. That was quite helpful and I will remember this.